# How to insert stringified json value at just one column in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, stringify

I am asked to enter a stringified json value in a column named show_cast in the format of    Release: and Date: but I don't have any idea how to do that. 
The table simply contains of three columns a token , time and genre.  The time has to be a stringified json.

I tried to simply put that using { and simple : but that doesn't seem to work. They say that {{release:,time:},{release:,date:},,,,} should be converted in stringify and then inserted into the database. I don't know how to do that and I don't see any resource like this out there. To be honest I didn't even know about this until I was given this task.

```
insert into show_reality values("project_123","{{release:2017,date:04-11},{release:2019,date:12-03}}","Action");
```

I have done this but I don't think it is a stringified json.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which data type is your  show_cast  column??

Comment: With MySQL 5.7 and up there's native JSON support https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: If you need idempotent data use a string blob but other than that go with the JSON data type

Comment: @scaisEdge It is the table name it's not any column.